# Custom menu order wordpress nav

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a custom wordpress menu which includes a link to the latest post from a category but it is pulling through after my other navigation items. Is there a way to move it to be second in the list?

```
                    <nav class="nav clearfix" role="navigation">
                        <ul>
                            <?php
                            wp_list_pages('title_li=&include=7,2,572,9,578');
                            query_posts('cat=3&posts_per_page=1');
                            if(have_posts());
                            while(have_posts()) :
                            the_post();
                            ?>
                                <li class="my-book-covers">
                                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">My Book Covers</a>
                                </li>
                            <?php
                            endwhile;
                            wp_reset_query();
                            ?>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself, seems the wordpress part of this site is dead.

```
<nav class="nav clearfix" role="navigation">
                        <ul>
                            <?php
                            wp_list_pages('title_li=&include=7');
                            ?>
                            <?php
                            query_posts('cat=3&posts_per_page=1');
                            if(have_posts());
                            while(have_posts()) :
                            the_post();
                            ?>
                                <li class="my-book-covers">
                                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">My Book Covers</a>
                                </li>
                            <?php
                            endwhile;
                            wp_reset_query();
                            ?>
                            <?php
                            wp_list_pages('title_li=&include=2,572,9,578');
                            ?>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
```